# index.php removed from all urls but homepage

Tags: index.php

I have following code in my .htaccess

RewriteEngine On

```
    # Removes index.php from ExpressionEngine URLs
    RewriteCond $1 !\.(gif|jpe?g|png)$ [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [PT]
```

That redirect works on all pages apart homepage is there any way to remove index.php from homepage?

Answer (score 1):

### EE 2.x

Go in to your general settings in your Control Panel.

```
(Site Name) -> CP Home -> Administration -> General Configuration
```

Remove `index.php` from the `URL to the root directory of your site` setting.

Docs: https://docs.expressionengine.com/v2/cp/admin/general_configuration.html

---

### EE 3.x

If it's EE 3.x, I believe you edit the `Website index page` setting that lives on `URL and Path Settings` page and remove `index.php` from that.

Docs: https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/cp/settings/urls.html

Comment: Hi jrothafer

Thank you for your help unfortunately that does not work.

I did that some time ago I have cleared the cache after that and still nothing.

This is EE 2.0 and system folder is not in root directory.

Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: I Have found in Config file editor -> $config['cp_url'] that has index.php , will I change that ?